# My spark paths are choppy!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am pretty sure there is a timing thing I am missing some where, but my particle system of sparks seems to shoot them out and then, instead of arcing gracefully, they abruptly change direction.

I like the direction of the arc but the abruptness is too sharp.

How do I soften it so they smoothly bend over?

[image: Sparks not bending correctly]

Here are my settings:

[image: Particle system settings]

Comment: I think you should increase the number of subframes. If it does not work then also change the integration method to RK4 (slower).

Comment: I brought it up to 10 subframes, which did seem a bit smoother. Going to try the RK4 and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure what the upper limit was to subframes. I went to RK4 but at 2 subframes, not much difference. Meanwhile, back at midpoint integration, jumping up to 40 subframes made a huge difference in the smoothness. And, in the short samples I was running, it seemed to actually save time. The bake was longer, tho.

Comment: Did some testing. Adding more subframes definitely helped to make the particle path smoother. However, as the subframe count increases, so does the bake time for the particles. There is a sweet spot between the two, where the path is smooth and the bake time isn't too long. But, I am not sure if there is an easy calculation, since there are so many other variables. With trial and error, 20 subframes works for this project.

Comment: To improve simulation accuracy you have to adjust two parameters, the number of subframes and/or integration method. Midpoint or Euler methods are faster but less accurate when the velocity or acceleration is very high. However, RK4 is slower but very accurate as compared to Midpoint and Euler methods in all cases. So the only way is, choose the integration method and number of subframes according to your simulation velocity or acceleration. May in future, blender particle system may have adaptive subframes and new RK4 method.